# How to trigger (simulate) keyboard clicks programatically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I am writing a function which when called will trigger the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> , <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> key presses programatically. Which is to zoom in, zoom out or reset the page.

```
function zoom(type) {
  if (type === 'zoomIn') {
    // trigger the key combination ctrl and +
  } else if (type === 'zoomOut') {
    // trigger the key combination ctrl and -
  } else {
    // else restore to default - ctrl 0
  }
}
```

I hope it is allowed to do this and not restricted because of security issues. If not, then some ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round? Your logic controlling the zoom and keystrokes triggering your logic? Logic triggering keystrokes might not be possible at all.

Comment: I have an action which will call this function which will either zoom in or zoom out the page.

Comment: But then rather refactor, using a `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` function which you can call from the action and also bind to to the specific key combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the save using following method, i.e. css zoom.

```js
var zoom_level = 100;
function zoom(type) {
  if (type === 'zoomIn') {
    zoom_level += 100;
  } else if (type === 'zoomOut') {
    zoom_level -= 100;
  } else {
    zoom_level = 100;
  }
  document.body.style.zoom = zoom_level + '%';
}
```

Comment: css zoom wont work in firefox, and below IE 11. so not able to use this.

Comment: You can use scale in that case.

Comment: had used scale, does not provide the desired behaviour. shrinks the body element as well